# Parsing log via Splunk and getting fields on multiple lines

Tags: regex, parsing, splunk

I am wanting to parse some logs via Splunk that are in one event but multiple lines.

```
Value1: 1000 MS
Value2: 300 MS
Value3: 1500 MS
```

I am having a hard time looking through Splunk documentation on how to extract these fields from one event.

What I have so far only parses the first field and adding more fields does not seem to work.

```
rex field=_raw "(?<object1>\w+): (?<totalms1>\d+) MS" | table object1, totalms1
```

Comment: The regex makes sense and it should match every one of those lines. I've never used Splunk, so I can't tell you if there's something else you need to do to match multiple lines.

Comment: In splunk as much as I know you can't put to named variable more occurance. However if you have for example 3 values each time then you may extract them as ms1, ms2 and ms3 which you may try to put together and summarize later.

Comment: In case you are looking for how to enable multiline matching, then use `(?m)` in the beginning of your regexp line: `_raw "(?m)(?<object1>.....`

Comment: What does your sample data actually look like? Is it JSON, XML, something else?